# Python(Pillow) or JS(canvas) - how to split image and make a right canvas edge as a mirror wrap

Tags: javascript, python, html5-canvas, python-imaging-library, wand

I'm trying to split image into pieces and get the same effect as on the photo below using HTML, CSS and JS or with python lib Pillow.

Original image:
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2aeZ.jpg)

Result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8AF8.jpg)

What I have tried so far is using HTML  and context.drawImage() function.
I was able to split the image into the pieces but I need to make each piece right edge as a mirror wrap, so it would look a 3d'ish so to say.
I've also tried Pillow in python as well, I was able to split the image into the pieces again, but I can't find a way to get the edges effect.

Here is python code example:

```
from PIL import Image

# Open the image
image = Image.open('image.jpeg')

# Divide the image into panels (assuming 3 panels for this example)
width, height = image.size
panel_width = width // 3
panel_height = height
panel1 = image.crop((0, 0, panel_width, panel_height))
panel2 = image.crop((panel_width, 0, panel_width * 2, panel_height))
panel3 = image.crop((panel_width * 2, 0, panel_width * 3, panel_height))

# Add a margin to the right side of each panel
margin = 10

panel1_with_margin = Image.new('RGB', (panel1.width + margin, panel1.height), (255, 255, 255))
panel1_with_margin.paste(panel1, (0, 0))
panel2_with_margin = Image.new('RGB', (panel2.width + margin, panel2.height), (255, 255, 255))
panel2_with_margin.paste(panel2, (0, 0))
panel3_with_margin = Image.new('RGB', (panel3.width + margin, panel3.height), (255, 255, 255))
panel3_with_margin.paste(panel3, (0, 0))

# Combine the panels into a single image
total_width = panel1_with_margin.width + panel2_with_margin.width + panel3_with_margin.width
max_height = max(panel1_with_margin.height, panel2_with_margin.height, panel3_with_margin.height)
combined_image = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height), (255, 255, 255))
combined_image.paste(panel1_with_margin, (0, 0))
combined_image.paste(panel2_with_margin, (panel1_with_margin.width, 0))
combined_image.paste(panel3_with_margin, (panel1_with_margin.width + panel2_with_margin.width, 0))

#Add mirroring and 3d effect here
#...Missed part of the code...

# Save the combined image
combined_image.save('combined_image.jpg')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: That is nothing more than a couple of narrow gradient ramps imposed upon the image. I see no mirroring of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of examples of image distortion, 3D-cubes and 3-D boxes using **ImageMagick** at the command-line [here](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#cube3d).

If you find something that you can get working on the commandline, you can do it just the same in Python using [wand](https://pypi.org/project/Wand/) which is a ctypes binding to **ImageMagick**.

Comment: Thanks mate! I think what I need is 3d Boxes, Perspective Layering. I'm trying now to convert that C code to Wand python, but getting error `wand.exceptions.WandError: wand contains no images `MagickWand-0' @ error/magick-image.c/MagickCompositeImage/2183`
Code - https://gist.github.com/fredskor/7d73df0c24532af68dac00a107ab8548

Comment: Maybe change the `image-manipulation` tag on your question to `wand` if you are trying that approach. Not sure which `C` code you are referring to - the link I gave is command-line (shell).

Comment: @FredSkor you need to init a canvas before composite. `with Image(width=500, height=500, background='black') as img:`